# How to set unique Salt Minion Ids when provisioned using vCenter

Tags: salt-stack, vcenter

For my use case, I am provisioning VM's using pre defined VM template in vCenter. The hostname in this template is already set, also salt minion is installed with no minion_id file. Once VM is provisioned and minion service starts, it automatically sets the hostname as minion id.

Now same template is used for provisioning more machines, due to which all machines gets same minion id.

One of the way to solve the problem is to manually change the minion_id file inside the newly created VM, but due to business reasons this is not possible.

Other way I can think about to set the unique minionid in VM guest advacned option like `guestinfo` and read it when VM is booting up, but this can only be set when VM is in powered off state.

I need help to set the different minion ids for each VM, how can this be accomplish without going inside the provisioned VM?

Comment: how do you install salt-minion in the first place ?

Comment: salt-minion is installed using pip. This was installed on the VM. After installation `salt-minion` service was stopped and `minion_id` file was deleted. Then this VM was converted into VM Template.

Comment: I suggest you to try something like this https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/startup.html or use cloud-init which allows you to run shell scripts in order to provision the virtual machine. if nothing worked for you then you may try to add a custom shell script before creating a template then make it check the minion_id and change it if it was not set

Answer (score 0):

In our case, hostname collisions are a possibility. So we set the minion id to the UUID of the device. On linux that's obtainable with `dmidecode -s system-uuid`, there's a similar command for windows.